# Postgres trigger interfering with 'on conflict do update set'

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, primary-key, sql-insert

I've got a SQL insert that should increment the `version` column and update the `time` column on a primary key conflict.

```
insert into items (pk, time, version, name)
        values (9999, now(), 1)
        on conflict (pk) do update set
          time = now(),
          version = items.version + 1,
          name = excluded.name
```

Everything works fine until I add a trigger to archive rows when an update happens. So if there's a row with version 1, and an insert happens later, the above query will increment the `version` column to be 2. But I want the old row with version 1 to go to the `archive` table.

But when I add the trigger below, the above insert doesn't update the version and time columns as it did without this trigger. How can I fix the trigger? Is it because I'm doing a `return old`, or because it's a `before update` trigger?

```
CREATE FUNCTION archivefunction() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
  insert into archive (pk, time, version, name)
    values (old.pk, old.time, old.version, old.name);
  return old;
  end
$$

CREATE TRIGGER archivetrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON items
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE archivefunction()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is for the `return old`, what does the return old is change the record values to be updated with the old values, you could do a `return new;` statement anyway for what you want, and I will do it in an after update trigger, the logic is that to archive after the list version is updated, not to archive before is updated